# Возможность админа переходить в аккаунт пользователя

Tags: php, авторизация, сессия

Вобщем такой вопрос, есть некая многопользовательская система.

В ней есть аккаунт админа и аккаунты пользователей.

Система на php, если подробнее то на codeigniter 3.
Авторизация используется штатная, на сессиях. У codeigniter свой механизм сессий, все тоже самое что и в нативном php, только ессии хранятся в БД.

Нужно реализовать такую возможность. Что бы админ, мог переходить в аккаунт любого пользователя.

То есть я сейчас нахожусь в аккаунте админа, у меня есть отдельная страница со всеми пользователями, я нажимаю на любого пользователя и попадаю в его аккаунт, то есть как бы логинюсь от его имени.
И могу делать в его аккаунте все тоже что и он сам, и как бы от его имени. Просто как бы сменил аккаунт на лету.

Естественно, так же нужна возможность выйти обратно, в аккаунт адимина. А так же возможность зайти в аккаунт юзера, даже если сам юзер онлайн в своем аккаунте. (Получаеться 2 человека асторизованы в одном аккаунте.)

Как это реализовать? Я не прошу написать мне рабочий код. Прошу подсказать алгоритм.

Дополню по ролям. Ролей в системе 3 штуки, administrator, user, moderator. Все по простому, в бд есть поле role, а в коде я проверяю, isAdmin(), isUser(), isModerator(), каждая из этих функций, так же проверяет и авторизован ли пользователь, isAdmin() true - значит юзер авторизован и имеет роль админа, и т.д.

Comment: можно при авторизации поставить дополнительный указатель в сессии мол я админ, а пользователям при авторизации указатель что просто запись. и при показе залогиненого контента сделать проверку на то какого типа запись, если админ или владелец записи пускать редактировать (и не нужно будет выходить обратно в админский режим, так как вы и так будете в нём оставаться) в cms по такому принципу устроены права доступа

Comment: А контент? Контент показывается для каждого юзера свой, берется по id юзера. Таким способом я только смогу переходить на страници предназначенные для юзеров, но контент будет браться по id админа, а нужно по id юзера, а id хранится в сессии.

Comment: то есть у вас страницы с контентом подгружаются не по урлу, а по айди который храниться в сессии (всё на одной странице или как) ? что-то не понятно...

Comment: Грубо говоря да. Например есть раздел, /fotos/ этот url для всех юзеров одинаков, но фотографии там у каждого юзера свои.

Comment: ну как то же вы собирались нажимать на пользователя и попадать  в его аккаунт.. так вот при нажатии передавайте его айди и при входе на страницу контента (при выборке записей с базы) подставляйте пользовательский айди при этом оставаясь залогиненым под админом...

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема ? Если id пользователя находиться в сессии, значит надо по запросу пользователя с правами админа выставить в его сессии id заказанного пользователя. оригинальный id админа при этом надо так же записать в сессию в отдельном свойстве, например lastId. Модифицировать функцию выхода из под пользователя на сайте таким образом, что бы она проверяла наличие lastId и возвращала его в поле id, вместо удаления сессии

Comment: Вариант второй: создать новую пользовательскую сессию, поменять сессионную куку на нее, при этом старую сессию перенести в другую куку, для последующего восстановления при выходе